# How to load csv into mysql with docker-compose?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I want to load a csv into my mysql container.

This is my docker-compose:

```
version: '3.7'

services: 
  db:
    image: mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment: 
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root123
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=test
      - MYSQL_USER=test
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=test123
    volumes:
      - './init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql'
      - './init_data:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init_data'
```

It does create the table, but it doesn't load the csv into the table.

As far as I have researched I have to pass this as an argument to mysql image, but I dont know how to add an argument by docker-compose.

--secure-file-priv=docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

[This](https://niole.net/how-to-load-csv-data-into-mysql-2bce9545822c) is what I am following.

But I don't want to use docker run.

Any help or tips are welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not add an argument to the docker compose for building, because docker compose can not build images. More clearly it can, by calling a `docker build` (using the info you gave in docker-compose.yml), but the things what you call on *building the image* can be defined only in the `Dockerfile`. You can not give commands in the docker-compose.yml for building.

What you can do: you can use the `mysql` image as a base to create your own image - with its own Dockerfile. Roughly so:

```
services:
  mymysql:
    build:
      context: ./mymysql
    ...other things in your docker compose...
```

That will define a new container named `mymysql`, whose definition is in the `./mymysql` directory. Create this directory and then put a `Dockerfile` into it. This Dockerfile should look like

```
FROM mysql:latest
USER mysql
RUN ...
RUN ...
```

In the `RUN` lines you can define the commands, what will be executed - on the pulled `mysql:latest` image and generate `mymysql` for you.

---

Alternative option: start the container and load the csv by running it. Then stop the container. After that a `docker commit fce2ea31 mymysql` will save the stopped container *as a new image*, in the name what you want. This is easier but much lesser reproducible, so I suggest to do the first.

Comment: I tried but I dont really know what to run in the docker file.
If I try to run an sql loading the data, it will give me an error like this ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement
And the error was the same using docker exec


`FROM mysql` 
`COPY ./init_data/ /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init_data/`
`COPY ./sql-scripts/ /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ `

Comment: @JPcode Well that is another problem. Mysql in the container is configured to allow such file loads only from a fixed directory. This is what `--secure-file-priv` does. Best is to turn this off. To do that, you need to check the container and modify it to execute mysql without this argument.

Comment: @JPcode I do not know that specific container well, but I know mysql and also docker in general. The `--secure-file-priv` is coming either from my.cnf,  or from a command line argument to the mysql. Find that config and override the settings: either by overwriting the config file with a COPY, or yet more better to extend the configuration. Alternatively, you can also override it by a command line argument to the mysqld (it is either called by a CMD or by some script in the container). The source (incl. Dockerfile) of the mysql:latest container would likely help a lot, and likely is available.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I used a command in the docker file `RUN sed -i 's/secure-file-priv= NULL/secure-file-priv= docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/g' /etc/mysql/my.cnf` and now it works! Thank you. (sorry it took me long) @peterh